# exclude contextual filters from breadcrumb

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs

I'm having a bit of a problem here.
I have a view which contains a list of items. At the top there are some vocabulary terms which you can click. When you click you go to a next page which shows a filtered list.

The problem is, on that new page, the filters are being added to the breadcrumb which I don't want. How can I exclude these filters from the breadcrumb?

example
The page with the complete list has this breadcrumb, which is good: 
Home » Opleidingen » Bijscholing

Next, if we click on 'gasten, hoe gaan we er mee om', the list gets filtered with the word 'gasten', on the next page the breadcrumb is like this: 
Home » Opleidingen » Bijscholing » Gasten, hoe gaan we ermee om? » » gasten » gasten

I want to be able to exclude this part '» » gasten » gasten'

Answer (score 2):

Click the "override breadcrumb" box in the settings pane for the contextual filter. You can override it with a custom value and you can use `%1`, `%2`. This won't exclude them but it will clean up the problem of the repeated words.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the breadcrumb from a view when using a contextual filter:
[image: To remove the breadcrumb from from a view when using a contextual filter]

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $page = menu_get_item();

  if (($page['page_callback'] == 'views_page') && ($page['page_arguments'][0] == VIEW_NAME)) {

    // Remove breadcrumbs from view arguments.
    $breadcrumb = array_slice(drupal_get_breadcrumb(), 0, 1);
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  }
}
```

This code removes all items from breadcrumb except Home link, and if you theme add current page to breadcrumb - you will see "Home > View name".
If not - just change parameters in array_slice fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the breadcrumb from contextual filter.

[image]